# How to make a Gui actually prompt for the dialog boxes?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, input, user-input

So I was trying to understand using a Gui in Java and did so by making a little guess the number game. It compiles correctly, however when I run the program it just shows the frame with "Congratulations you win!" at the top. My main question is why the dialog boxes aren't popping up at all and what I should do to fix that. On a related note, when I had the code as `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"Play again? Y/N")` I got the error message "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context." My secondary, and much less important question, is how to make the message be in the center of the box vertically as well as horizontally.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class RandomNumberGame{
            public static JLabel higherThan;
            public static JPanel tooHigh;
            public static JLabel lowerThan;
            public static JPanel tooLow;
            public static JPanel exactlyCorrect;
            public static JLabel correctAnswer;
            public static JFrame guiFrame;
        public static void main(String[] args){
            RandomFun();
            }
        public static void RandomFun()
        {
            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
            guiFrame = new JFrame();


            guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            guiFrame.setTitle("Fun Games!");
            guiFrame.setSize(500,500);
            guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            guiFrame.setVisible(true);      


            final JPanel tooHigh = new JPanel();
                 higherThan = new JLabel("Too High!");
            final JPanel tooLow = new JPanel();
                 lowerThan  = new JLabel("Too Low!");
            final JPanel exactlyCorrect = new JPanel();
                 correctAnswer = new JLabel("Congratulations, you won!");

            tooHigh.add(higherThan);
            tooLow.add(lowerThan);
            exactlyCorrect.add(correctAnswer);
            guiFrame.add(tooHigh, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            guiFrame.add(tooLow, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            guiFrame.add(exactlyCorrect, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }
        public static void GuessNumber(){
            String again;
            String lastGuess = "0";
            boolean moreGame=true;
            int lastGuessInt = Integer.parseInt(lastGuess.toString());
            int winner = (int) (Math.random()*999+1);
            while(moreGame){
                lastGuess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a Number");
                    if(winner < lastGuessInt){
                        tooHigh.setVisible(true);
                        tooLow.setVisible(false);
                        exactlyCorrect.setVisible(false);
                        }
                    else if(winner > lastGuessInt){
                        tooHigh.setVisible(false);
                        tooLow.setVisible(true);
                        exactlyCorrect.setVisible(false);
                        }
                    else{
                        tooHigh.setVisible(false);
                        tooLow.setVisible(false);
                        exactlyCorrect.setVisible(true);
                        moreGame=false;
                        }
            }
                    again = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Play again? Y/N");
            switch(again){
                case "y": case "Y":
                    GuessNumber();
                    break;
                case "n": case "N":
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                }                   
            }
        }
```

Comment: The only time you call `GuessNumber()` is from inside the method itself.

Comment: Most likely the `while` loop inside `GuessNumber()` is incorrect. I suggest you learn more about event-driven programming.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: it has nothing to do with the while loop, since the `GuessNumber()` method is not called by the main method or by any code that runs off of the main method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Exactly. I addressed that issue in my first comment. My second comment is a suggestion about a possible logic error that will be encountered when the OP fixes the current problem. Although, now that I look more closely, the `while` loop might not really be a problem since `showInputDialog()` is synchronous.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: ah, I didn't see your first comment, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the "mis-behavior":

- Your main method calls `RandomFun()`
- And `RandomFun()` then creates a JFrame and displays.
- It adds 3 JPanels **all** in the BorderLayout.CENTER position!
- Thus only the last JPanel will show because it will cover all the previously added JPanels as per BorderLayout's documented behavior.
- Thus your code is behaving exactly as you'd expect it to.
- Other issues include a gross over-use of the static modifier, calling `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame **before** adding all components, setting the size of the JFrame, creating a method, `GuessNumber()` that is never called by viable running code, code not adhering to Java naming conventinons (methods and fields should begin with a lower-case letter, classes with an upper-case letter),...

If I were in your shoes, I'd put the GUI coding to the side as I'd first want to concentrate on learning Java basics, including avoiding all static methods and fields and instead creating true OOPs-compliant classes, since this understanding is critical prior to delving into GUI coding. Just a few weeks of study should be enough to get you strong enough to then try some Swing coding.

---

My attempt to create a guessing game program:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class RandomNumberGame2 extends JPanel {
   private static final int LOW = 0;
   private static final int HIGH = 100;
   public static final String START_GAME = "Please guess the random number between "
         + LOW + " and " + HIGH;
   public static final String TO_HIGH = "Your guess is too high. Please try again";
   public static final String TO_LOW = "Your guess is too low. Please try again";
   public static final String CONGRATS_YOU_WIN = "Congratulations, you win!!!";

   private Random random = new Random();
   private int randomNumber; // holds the randomly selected number
   private JTextField inputField = new JTextField(5); // where user enters guess
   private JButton submitButton = new JButton(new SubmitAction("Submit", KeyEvent.VK_S));
   private JButton resetButton = new JButton(new ResetAction("Reset", KeyEvent.VK_R));
   private JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel(START_GAME, SwingConstants.CENTER);

   public RandomNumberGame2() {
      // so field will select all when gains focus
      inputField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            JTextComponent textComp = (JTextComponent) e.getSource();
            textComp.selectAll();
         }
      });
      // so input field will submit number if enter is pressed
      inputField.addActionListener(submitButton.getAction());

      JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(); // uses flow layout by default
      centerPanel.add(new JLabel("Enter number here:"));
      centerPanel.add(inputField);
      centerPanel.add(submitButton);
      centerPanel.add(resetButton);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(statusLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      resetGame();
   }

   public void resetGame() {
      randomNumber = random.nextInt(HIGH - LOW) + LOW;
      inputField.setText("");
      statusLabel.setText(START_GAME);
      inputField.requestFocusInWindow();
      inputField.selectAll();
   }

   private class SubmitAction extends AbstractAction {
      public SubmitAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         try {
            int input = Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText().trim());
            if (input > randomNumber) {
               statusLabel.setText(TO_HIGH);
            } else if (input < randomNumber) {
               statusLabel.setText(TO_LOW);
            } else {
               statusLabel.setText(CONGRATS_YOU_WIN);
            }
            inputField.requestFocusInWindow();
            inputField.selectAll();

         } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(RandomNumberGame2.this,
                  "Please enter only integer data", "Non-numeric Data Error",
                  JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            inputField.setText("");
         }
      }
   }

   private class ResetAction extends AbstractAction {
      public ResetAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         resetGame();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      RandomNumberGame2 mainPanel = new RandomNumberGame2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fun Games 2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```